# magento - how to create reorder using api?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create reorder using API but getting **Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Not all products are available in the requested quantity'**

but I still want to place items in cart using reorder , here is my code -

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$orderId =  $_REQUEST['order_id'];

try {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    if (!Mage::helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($order)) {
        return 'reorder not allowed';
    }

    if ($order->getId()) {
        $order->setReordered(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);
        $reorder = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->initFromOrder($order);

        //We needed additional logic for shipping rates
        $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
                ->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod())
                ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();
        $reorder->createOrder();
    }

    echo json_encode(array('status' => true ,
        'order_id' => $new_order,
        'message' => 'Order created successfully'));

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => false , 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

can anybody help please!!! Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You can set super mode on quote. This tells Magento that the quote is created by an admin and a lot of checks will be skipped (like the stock check). Just search the codebase for `getIsSuperMode` to see how it works.

So, to avoid that exception and force adding your products to cart, add `setIsSuperMode(true)` on the quote.

Comment: can you please post working codes ? or any reference link ? Thanks much!